# Inserting PHP while in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to embed a data picker calendar in my php site. The code, which came off the shelf from DatePicker, allows to select some pre-highlighted dates, which is good as I have a list in a db table with the dates I need.

However, I have had no success in finding a way to include php within the script, or the other way round.

The original calendar script is as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function() {
$("#txtDate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    var SelectedDates = {};
    SelectedDates[new Date('02/24/2014')] = new Date('02/24/2014');
 SelectedDates[new Date('03/10/2014')] = new Date('03/10/2014');

    $('#txtDate').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
            if (Highlight) {
            return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
        }
        else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    }
});
});
  </script>
```

I would like to be able to select a long list of dates to go in 
    SelectedDates[new Date('03/10/2014')] = new Date('03/10/2014');

so my original idea was to do as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var SelectedDates = {};

  <?php 
$query = "SELECT eventDate FROM database.calendar WHERE tag='R' AND competition='1'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $eventdate = $row[0];

SelectedDates[new Date('$eventdate')] = new Date('$eventdate');
}
?>
```

Sadly, this doesn't work (and neither do any of the various attempts to re-add  tags within the PHP.

Any idea? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You forgot `echo` operator. don't u?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Still learning, but I am going to follow through and try and figure out what's the best for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close your PHP tags to output JavaScript (or use `echo` as mentioned in a comment):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var SelectedDates = {};

    <?php 
    $query = "SELECT eventDate FROM database.calendar WHERE tag='R' AND competition='1'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $eventdate = $row[0];
        ?>
        SelectedDates[new Date('<?php echo $eventdate; ?>')] = new Date('<?php echo $eventdate; ?>');
        <?php
    }
    ?>
});
```

Although I should mention that what you are trying to do is not really ideal. Do the PHP `while` loop separately, get that into an array, and `json_encode` that.

Comment: Thank you for this - I shall try that right away. Still not overly familiar with arrays but they seem to be cropping up more and more - one for the lessons soon!